# How to read all .jpg files from folder and subfolders and convert it into single .tif file

Tags: python, arrays, image, opencv, image-processing

I hope you are doing well. I have a problem I want to convert .jpg image files into a single tiff file

I have the folders arranged in that way. First, the code reads all .jpg files from the folder and then converts them into single .tif file

How can I do it in python?

```
Dataset

....Class1
........image1.jpg
........image2.jpg
........image3.jpg

....Class2
........image4.jpg
........image5.jpg
........image6.jpg
```

Can anybody help me in that

I have attached the images
Image 1:
[image: image2]

Image 2:

[image: Image1]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "a single tiff file"? Do you want to combine them all in a single image? With glob of path/*.jpg and subfolders=true you can find all the jpg files. Do with them whatever you want.

Comment: @Micka How can i do can you please share some code for that. yes i want to combine all into single image. like make it 3d

Comment: @cgohlke but its not working , i have attached image aboves

Answer (score 0):

Assume all image are of the same size and you want to lay all your images in a grid:

```py
import glob

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


def imgrid(imarray, cols=4):
    """
    Create a grid of images from an array of images.
    """
    cols = int(cols)
    assert cols >= 1
    N, H, W, C = imarray.shape
    rows = N // cols + int(N % cols != 0)
    grid = np.reshape(
        np.transpose(np.reshape(imarray, [rows, cols, H, W, C]),
                     [0, 2, 1, 3, 4]), [rows * H, cols * W, C])
    return grid


# Glob all jpg files
fnames = glob.glob('./Dataset/*/*.jpg')

# Read all images into an array
imarray = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in fnames])

# Merge the images into a single image and save as a tiff
Image.fromarray(imgrid(imarray)).save('merged.tiff')
```

Comment: getting an error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)

Comment: I don't want to save as grid, i want to save as each file in .tif file for example i have four image, i want to make a single .tif value which have 3D (H,W,Image)

Comment: So am I correct to assume those images are greyscale image with shape of (H, W, 1)?

Comment: Ngyun, yeah you are right but its not working , i have attached image aboves